# Ajax Post with FormData never reach error or success

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call POST with a FormData with parameters and files.
Debugging the call, it's never reach neither error or success, and it doesn't reach controller.

The FormData contains a structure with an object mapped as *'RegisterMerchantInput'*

Given as global:

```
const fdata = new FormData();
```

Call:

```
var content = {
   businessName: $('#business-id').val(),
   (...)
};
buildFormData(content);
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/Owners/savemerchant',
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   cache: false,
   data: fdata,                        
   success: function () {
      window.location.href = "../Stores/StoresList";
   },
   error: function (err) {
      window.location.href = "../Home/Error";
   }
});
```

To Build Form Data:

```
function buildFormData(data, parentKey) {
    if (data && typeof data === 'object' && !(data instanceof Date) && !(data instanceof File)) {
       Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
         buildFormData(data[key], parentKey ? `${parentKey}[${key}]` : key);
       });
    } else {
        const value = data == null ? '' : data;
        fdata.append(parentKey, value);
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("savemerchant")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveMerchant(RegisterMerchantInput model){...}
```

Now I tried specifying [FromBody] and [FromForm]
I tried with 
 - async: false
 - contentType: undefined
and various combination of this parameters.

The call is like pending in nowhere...

NOTE: in the FormData there are also files, so I cannot serialize it in JSON

EDIT:
Request:

[image]

Timing:

[image]

EDIT 2:
The FormData to Send, logged is (note the datas are all dumb but correctly typed):

```
businessName: Tester Merchant
vatCode: a
debitorAccount: a
bicCode: a
currencyMandate: a
currencyMandateDate: 2000-01-01
commissionMandate: a
commissionMandateDate: 2000-01-01
city: Avigliano
postalCode: 85101
address: Via Vai 4
name: Bala
surname: Laika
telephone: a
email: bala@laika.com
password: Pa55word1!
country: IT
province: CZ
stores[0][banner]: b
stores[0][description]: b
stores[0][email]: b@b.b
stores[0][website]: b
stores[0][telephone]: b
stores[0][category]: b
stores[0][latitude]: 41.9022448
stores[0][longitude]: 12.456290099999933
stores[0][country]: IT
stores[0][province]: BA
stores[0][city]: b
stores[0][postalCode]: b
stores[0][address]: b
stores[0][terminals][0][store]: b
stores[0][terminals][0][model]: c
stores[0][terminals][0][concept]: c
stores[0][terminals][0][externalCode]: c
stores[0][logo]: (binary)
```

The image is 2438byte.
After ten minutes my pc crashes with 100% Disk fullness

Comment: If the success or error handlers are never hit, and the controller receives no data, are you sure the request is even being sent at all? Under what event is the code running? Have you checked the console to see what the network traffic is doing?

Comment: Edited the original post with image of network request

Comment: How much data are you sending in the request?

Comment: Edited the original post with FormData logged with                     
for (var pair of fdata.entries()) {
     console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
}